# How to call template operator?

Tags: c++

How can I call declared operator of the class as following code;

```
class CChQuAuth
{
    public:
        CChQuAuth()
        {
        }
};

class CChQuCached
{
    public:
        CChQuCached()
        {
        }

        template <typename  _ChClass>
        operator bool();
};

template <typename  _ChClass>
CChQuCached::operator bool()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    CChQuCached ChQuCached;

    ChQuCached.operator bool<CChQuAuth>(); // compile error !
}
```

I got compile error with VS22.

to solve thanks for your help...

Comment: Conversion operators cannot be called directly. THen how do you expect to use template conversion operator in context where template parameter can't be deduced?

Comment: I don't think there is any mechanism for passing a template argument to a conversion operator. You should implement this as a member function instead. Even for other operators that support it, I would not recommend it. It forces users to use the operator as a function, at which point you might as well just provide a clearer member function instead.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie A conversion operator can be called directly. For example `foo.operator int()` will call `operator int` on `foo`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmm, I thought that one is called something else, but fine. That wouldn't work for template as `operator bool` isn't  really a name,  `bool` is a typename. name here would be bool and it's not a name of template as they cannot match built-in types. `template <typename  T> operator typename some_previously_defined_template<T> ()` would work

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The problem is not that conversion operators (even templated ones) cannot be called directly, it's that their template arguments cannot be explicitly provided, meaning they need to be deduced. If we change the template head of the templated bool conversion operator above to `template <typename  _ChClass = CChQuAuth>` then it is fine to call it as `ChQuCached.operator bool();` (however we wont be able to call any other specialization of it).

Comment: @dfrib if typename of operator is dependant on type, we can. `auto a = ChQuCached.operator std::vector<int>();` would work for my example. Thing is it's called invocation or something like that, my memory is fuzzy. Doesn't follow generic call rules. OP fails, because `bool` is not a name of template.

Comment: <https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#mem-5.sentence-2>: Seems like it's not possible

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You should post that as an alternative solution.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It's a bit of a mess, but a conversion function template does not name a template-id, which is the only context where explicit template parameters may be provided (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1). In your example, when the conversion-to type is a type template parameter, then the `T` is still deduced from the call, it is not explicitly provided (even if it may look like it is). Peculiarly the same does not hold for operator-function-id:s, meaning `template <typename T> T operator+() { return T{}; }` can legally be called as `A{}.operator+<int>();`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Afaict OP is not after conversion to `T`, OP is after conversion to `bool` but where a template type, directly into the conversion function (not possible to provide explicitly, as I've written above) could e.g. be used to static dependency injection.

Comment: @dfrib They are suggesting a solution where the template argument is embedded in the return type of the conversion function, where the argument can be deduced.

Comment: @Artyer That's right, for `operator bool` lexem  `bool<type>` would be a type-id with explicit template-parameter list, but it's incorrect as `bool` is not a template.  For `operator std::vector<T>` lexem `std::vector<int>` would a name of conversion function,

Comment: Sidenote: `_ChClass` is a reserved identifier in all contexts, because it starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Declaring it, e.g. as a template parameter is not allowed.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `auto a = ChQuCached.operator std::vector<int>();` is not an example of an conversion-function template call with an explicit template-parameter list: the type template parameter `T` of the conversion-function template is deduced from `std::vector<int>` as `int` or as `std::vector<int>` depending on its signature. The problem here is not that `bool` is not a template, it is that you cannot explicitly refer to a specialization of a conversion-function template, as a conversion-function-id [is not a template-id](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1).

Comment: @dfrib I wasn't arguing with that. I was going from compiler's perspective. It would be even problematic to implement such syntax without so me dubius side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way

> There is no syntax to form a template-id ([temp.names]) by providing
> an explicit template argument list ([temp.arg.explicit]) for a
> conversion function template

But  there are options to choose from.

1. Use a general member-function template instead. That's how `std::tuple` works.
2. Create own template type convertible to `bool`. Define conversion operator to that type.
3. Consider that you actually should do something else. Perhaps visitor pattern is what you're looking for.

Using a default template argument for a template conversion function to a non-template type OR using a template-id as target for conversion function are ONLY ways how one can pass a template-argument while instantiating and invoking said conversion function. E.g.:

```
class CChQuAuth {
    public:
        CChQuAuth() { }
};

template <typename  T>
struct MyBool {
   bool v; 
   operator bool() { return v;};
}; 

class CChQuCached {
    public:
        CChQuCached() {
        }

       template <typename T>
       operator typename ::MyBool<T>();  
};

template <typename  T>
CChQuCached::operator typename ::MyBool<T>()
{
    return MyBool<T>();
}

int main()
{
    CChQuCached ChQuCached;

    bool b = ChQuCached.operator MyBool<CChQuAuth>();
}
```

That's just an example and no way a proper boilerplate code. Note that conversion operator name expected to be a nested type-id first, and in this case it is given as fully qualified one, with `::`.

Comment: Well, what would be the point of all that anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to make it a regular function:

```
struct Type {
    template <typename T>
    bool to_bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Type var;
    var.to_bool<char>();
}
```